# What does the line starting with double quote mean in C?

Tags: c

I was asked in one of the interviews, what does the following line print in C? In my opinion following line has no meaning:

```
"a"[3<<1];
```

Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: `"` means the same as when a `"` *doesn't* start a line. But yes, since the value is discarded (unless the line is continued) .. then it's possibly just silly code (but look at the previous line).

Comment: The expression `"a"[3<<1]` should be, after compilation, identical to the expression `(3<<1)["a"]`. Can you figure why? Although the evaluated content is clearly undefined here, it would be completely valid if you switch the *shift* operator: `"a"[3>>1]`, `(3>>1)["a"]` (both are valid expressions and return the char `\0`).

Answer (score 13):

Surprisingly, it does have a meaning: it's an indexing into an array of characters that represent a string literal. Incidentally, this particular one indexes at `6`, which is outside the limits of the literal, and is therefore undefined behavior.

You can construct an expression that works following the same basic pattern:

```
char c = "quick brown fox"[3 << 1];
```

will have the same effect as

```
char c = 'b';
```

Comment: Aren't "does have a meaning" and "is undefined behavior" two contradictory statements?

Comment: I don't think so. There's the syntactical meaning "access array element", and the semantic meaning "undefined behaviour".

Answer (score 3):

Think of this:

```
"Hello world"[0]
```

is `'H'`

`"Hello world"` is a string literal. A string literal is an array of `char` and is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array in an expression. `"Hello world"[0]` means the first element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

It does have meaning. Hint: `a[b]` means exactly the same as `*(a+b)`. (I don't think this is a great interview question, though.)

Comment: Especially the question's not great since whatever the code means, it certainly isn't guaranteed to *print* anything. Lack of calls to I/O functions etc.

Comment: Oh, there's tons wrong with it. Incidentally, I just noticed that when I looked at the question I misread it and thought it was asking about `(3<<1)["a"]` rather than `"a"[3<<1]`. (On account of the questioner's apparent bafflement, which is a much more reasonable response to the former than the latter.) And I bet "rubber boots" is on the right track and the question actually asked in the interview had `>>` not `<<`.

Answer (score 2):

`"a"` is an array of 2 characters, `'a'`, and `0`.  `3 << 1` is `3*2 = 6`, so it's trying to access the 7th element of a 2-element array.  That is undefined behavior.

(Also, the code doesn't print anything, even if the undefined behavior is removed, since no printing functions are called.)

Answer (score 1):

"some_string"[i] returns the ith character of the given string. `3<<1` is 6. So `"a"[3<<1]` tries to return the 6th character of the string "a".

In other words the code invokes undefined behavior (and thus, in a sense, really does have no meaning) because it's accessing a char array out of bounds.